# Set the list of acceptable values in a GWT ValueListBox based on an EnumSet?

Tags: java, gwt, enums, gwt-editors

Given that I have this entity as part of an editor chain:

```
public class Commission implements Serializable
{   

    private EnumSet<CommissionType> commissionTypes;
    private CommissionType type; // must exist in commissionTypes

    private String value;

    public Commission()
    {

    }
}
```

and this editor for it:

```
public class CommissionEditor extends Composite implements Editor<Commission>
{
    private static CommissionEditorUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(CommissionEditorUiBinder.class);

    interface CommissionEditorUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, CommissionEditor>
    {
    }

    @UiField(provided = true)
    ValueListBox<CommissionType> type = new ValueListBox<CommissionType>(new AbstractRenderer<CommissionType>()
    {
        @Override
        public String render(CommissionType object)
        {
            return object == null ? "" : object.toString();
        }
    });

    @UiField
    TextBox value;

    public CommissionEditor()
    {
        type.setAcceptableValues(Arrays.asList(CommissionType.values()));

        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

}
```

At the moment the ValueListBox renders all possible options for CommissionType, like this:

[image: ValueListBox rendering all possible values of the Enum]

The EnumSet could contain between 1 and 4 of the possible options, depending on the particular entity. Is there a way to make the ValueListBox only render the options in the EnumSet and then save the value in commissionType?

Bear in mind that I want to set the value of commissionType as well.

Comment: I like the styling you used. Is that twitter bootstrap?

Comment: Cheers! Yes, it's GWT-Bootstrap with the Cosmo theme from bootswatch.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to solve it:

1.) If you have a direct access to the `CommissionEditor` then create a setter in it call it when you edit the entity:

```
public void setAcceptableValues(List<CommissionType> values) {
    type.setAcceptableValues(values);

}
```

And call it like this when you call `driver.edit(entity);`:

```
commissionEditor.setAcceptableValues(commission.getCommissionTypes());
```

2.) Instead of extending the `Editor` interface you can extend the [ValueAwareEditor](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/editor/client/ValueAwareEditor.html) and in the `setValue()` method call `setAcceptableValues` with the corresponding values.

Approach 2 is probably the cleaner approach.

Comment: Thanks! I was just implementing ValueAwareEditor as you answered.